# Three.JS, mapping a cube to a sphere and Gnomic Projection

Tags: 3d, three.js, geometry

Noob alert!...

In order to avoid the singularities at the poles when wrapping a texture around a default sphere, I am attempting to implement the standard technique of using a cube as the base geometry.

So here [cube wireframe](http://weather.wilmslowastro.com/test/three-cube/cubeWire.htm) I move the vertices of a BoxGeometry to the surface of the enclosing sphere, this seems to produce a nice regular lattice.

Then I take a rectilinear grid and apply a transform using 'CubeMap' or NASA's 'G.Projector' to convert the rectilinear map to a Gnomic Cube map (6 maps, one for each 'face' of the cube). When I apply these maps to the cube however I do not get regular lines of latitude/longitude. See here: [plain grid maps](http://weather.wilmslowastro.com/test/three-cube/cubePlain.htm)

Any idea where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I have found the problem, my projection of the vertices on to the sphere was incorrect. I was using...

```js
function displaceVertex(vertex) {
  var x2 = (vertex.x/radius) * (vertex.x/radius);
  var y2 = (vertex.y/radius) * (vertex.y/radius);
  var z2 = (vertex.z/radius) * (vertex.z/radius);

  vertex.x = vertex.x * Math.sqrt(1 - (y2 * 0.5) - (z2 * 0.5) + ((y2 * z2) / 3));
  vertex.y = vertex.y * Math.sqrt(1 - (z2 * 0.5) - (x2 * 0.5) + ((z2 * x2) / 3));
  vertex.z = vertex.z * Math.sqrt(1 - (x2 * 0.5) - (y2 * 0.5) + ((x2 * y2) / 3));
}
```

which distributed the vertices evenly across the spherical surface. What is required is to project them to the surface, I have changed the above to the following and the project now works OK...

```js
function displaceVertex(vertex) {
  vertex.setLength(radius);
 
}
```

Comment: How about `vertex.setLength( radius );`

Comment: Ha! Told you I was noob, thanks, that is perfect! I'm also a noob on StackOverflow, do you have to post that as an answer so I can flag it?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just improve your own answer and then accept your own answer.